# Using Lucene for searching name with different combination

Tags: sql, search, solr, lucene

We have a asp.net Web based application, which requires a name to be searched from a Huge Name database which is around 2 million names. And this also we require it to be done in real-time. We have searched and found that Lucene can give a fast search. We have names in the transaction which can be in  different order or could be part of a complete name or could be mis-spelled. The user has the option to provide the percentage of matching accuracy required. We use a SQL server 2008 R2 database. If any users has prior experience with a similar requirement, would appreciate your feedback / solution.

Regards

Comment: Sounds like you should be indexing your name database as a Lucene Dictionary and use the SpellChecker. This allows you to set the accuracy of the match and can also suggest similar words or names in your case.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a full fledged enterprise commercial project to me with the requirements you gave here than a Lucene technical question.  Yes, Lucene can handle that. You need to write special tokenizer with overlapping variable length char n-gram  index  and index these n-grams against the lucene "document". During query phase you will need to do the same by breaking your input name into n-gram chars and search against Lucene.

Comment: This requirement is part of a application. I am new to Lucene, is there a way, I can be assisted or somebody has developed a similar solution. I tried using the DB but was taking more time than expected. Since the search as to be done real-time at the front-office, processing time is a factor to be considered.

Comment: The answer is very lengthy. First i thought of elaborating on what i suggested above then i realized i can just put a link to an article explaining just what i proposed above. Here is the link : http://www.opensourceconnections.com/2013/08/21/name-search-in-solr/

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted in my application, but how can i get the code or the solution. Apart I am not sure, if it also checks for mis-spelled names and we can also provide the percentage of matching required. Arun is there a way to get the coding / configuration details, we would very much appreciate that support.